# MPU9255: Unreliable AK8963 Communications

Tags: i2c, spi, teensy

I'm currently trying to communicate with the InvenSense MPU9255 9-Axis IMU using the FreeIMU software on a Teensy3.2.
See comment below for link to FreeIMU code being used (don't have enough reputation).

I know that my setup is correct for the following reasons:

- I can successfully communicate with the MPU6050 portion reliably.
- I can successfully communicate with the AK8963 at startup, reading the correct address (72) as well as data.
- I have double checked the FreeIMU code to ensure that it reads 7 bytes (as opposed to 6) when collecting data to prevent blocking.
- Pin 1 is connected to VDDIO.
- Added copious delays between each read/ write instruction.

Things I have tried to resolve the problem:

- Turning it off and on again (time before failure ~instantaneous -> 10min)
- Switching between different IMU's, wires, and processors.
- Soft resetting the IMU after each read cycle (dies after 1 or 2 cycles).
- Looking through forums (online, & InvenSense's Developers Corner).
- Emailing InvenSense for further solutions.
- Adding an additional 10uF capacitance between the power and ground lines. (No effect).
- Scoping the Auxiliary I2C Clock and Data lines:
  [image: Aux Clock (Pin 7) at point of failure.]
  [image: Aux Data (Pin 21) at point of failure.]

Comment: Code: https://github.com/mjs513/FreeIMU-Updates
Teensy: https://github.com/mjs513/FreeIMU-Updates

Comment: Could somebody with a higher reputation add the tags "MPU9250" and "AK8963"? Again, I don't have enough rep. I say MPU9250 instead of MPU9255 because both chips are very similar to each other, but the MPU9250 is the more popular. Just in my case I have the unpopular version :p

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking, but there's literally tens of thousands of IC families out there. While it makes sense to have a tag for very common microcontrollers and basic components, having a tag for your favourite IMU makes no sense – it clutters the tag catalog and also doesn't give your question more visibility than a descriptive title.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK, fair enough. I know what the solution is (see below) but as I couldn't see anything else online about it I figured I'd add it for all to see :) Hopefully my mentioning of the IMU's etc. in the answer & question will be enough for Google.

Comment: to be frank, this doesn't seem to be an IMU-related problem at all. You simply didn't build a good digital communication line. For things like I²C and SPI, a lot of design guides exist!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would personally disagree (but please tell me if my logic does not hold, and why). Both the I2C and SPI comms worked flawlessly when communicating to the primary device (6-axis imu) irrespective of distance. The isolated secondary device (magnetometer), which requires usage of the aux I2C, had sporadic noise issues though. The datasheet itself clarifies that the aux I2C pins should be left floating if no further devices are to be connected. Hence, the noise stems from circuitry internal to the IMU, and the datasheet was inadequate in informing of any fixes to issues like this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Combine that with the fact that the solution required a capacitance between clock and a chip select (which seems completely unintuitive to me) and I feel as though there is something specific going on inside of the MPU9255 itself. Also, I did make at least a half decent stab at making said communications. Knowing that the line is long I dropped the clock frequency. Pull up resistors and ESD protection were applied to all lines. Shielded wires were used initially, and I only stopped using them for debugging.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I could have gone further, but I felt I had taken reasonable precautions by that point. (I presumed twisted pairing to be overkill as the application environment for my proof of concept is not that bad, and the cable length won't be *that* long). If I've made a schoolboy error, it was not from lack of trying :p and if I have then please point it out so that I may learn from my mistakes.

Comment: good points, really! I must admit I haven't been able to read that from your question, though :)

Comment: Do you think it'd be worthwhile updating the question to point it out? When writing I was more thinking "surface issues" and "solution" than all of the other design considerations that had gone into it.

Comment: hm, maybe! I don't really know, it feels like you've been doing a lot of research your own, and you have a different question now, and maybe asking that separately with all that info would make sense?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure what the new question would be to be honest. I've already emailed everything  (code, PCB designs, tests, etc.) to InvenSense directly (as IC internals is probably something only they would know :p). Beyond that I've left an answer below so others in my position can more readily resolve the same issue so I'm kind of happy as it is. I'll update the question with the extra info a bit later and leave it at that I think. Thanks for your input! :D

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been quite old but, I come across the same situation when I use MPU9250 spi with long wire, and read Ak8963 by the MPU9250 Aux I2C. Oscilloscope on SPI SCLK and Aux SCL shows that when there is a SPI reading and I2C reading happen at the same time, the I2C would hang and halt, I can see crosstalk spikes on I2C signal whenever there is SPI CLK edges.
Strangely enough I change the AUX SCL probe attenuation ratio from 10x to 1x the spike reduces and all the transaction functions normally for hours. The input resistance of that probe is 10Mohm in 10x and 1Mohm in 1x so I think reduce the I2C load impedance would minimize the crosstalk spikes.
Have you tested the root cause of this, or better solution? I wrote a test sketch to simply manipulate each SPI io high and low, and only SCLK would have this effect on effecting AUX SCL. Pull up AUX SCL with 2k resistor does not work. This happens only when SCLK wire is long so I think there might be something wrong with the SCLK bus capacitance and for some magic it affect AUX SCL.

Answer (score 0):

After more playing around, it turned out that the length of wire between the Teensy and MPU9255/ MPU9250 was a variable which, when short, would allow the AK8963 to function reliably.

After further experimenting (aka, keeping all but 1 cable short, and the last cable long) it turned out that the clock line (pin 23 NOT the Aux Clock) was the source of the trouble.

Long story short, adding an extra 2nF capacitor (or 2 1nF capacitors in my case) between the clock pin and AD0/SD0 (Pin 9, close to the IMU) allowed for 200cm clock line with reliable functionality.

### EDIT:

Originally I thought I had connected the capacitors to ground. In actual fact I had connected them to pin 9. The difference here is that I have multiple IMU's to read on the same bus, so pin 9 (AD0, which changes the last bit of the IMU's address) is acting as a kind of "chip select".

I am unsure as to why this resolves the issues, or if this carries over to the SPI setup as well. If I have time, I will test this out also.

Also, I have tested this when all wires are 100cm long, and the fix still works.

Comment: SNR quality on the traces shown certainly show significant room for improvement from a communication point of view for Grounding, crosstalk, balanced twisted pairs, lack of shielding or CM chokes, ground inductance etc.